# Creating a path node at projected intersection between line segment and edge

Tags: inkscape, svg

How would I go about inserting a node on my current path at the projected intersection between an edge and a line segment continuation?

To more fully explain what I'm after, I actually want to be able to separate that bottom horizontal segment from the vertical section. I'm wanting to create two paths that fully make that vector graphic, but in two pieces. My current thought is to add the path node at the intersection, and then delete out the nodes that I don't need.

Here is the object:

[image: Path Object]

I want to continue the line marked in red, and then add a node at the intersection where these paths would occur at the red line and left edge:

[image: Path Object Markup]

Comment: One way I found: Draw a Bezier line starting from the right-most node of the red line to the other node along the red line using the cusp node snap handles. Resize the Bezier curve by holding `Alt` + `Shift` + `Ctrl` which continued the Bezier line along the same angle. I then inserted a node at the snap intersection of the object. Is there a better way?

Comment: Not sure about better, but if you construct it using a skewed rectangle for the base of the L shape, then do a Union boolean, the top left node of the rectangle will be preserved. [see example](https://imgur.com/BfjbEux)

Comment: you can often use the shape itself as a ruler.  Copy the shape then snap the corner of the rightmost coner to the L and use that as intersection guide. The benefit here is that you can use it to do as wild snapping as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Since the shape is made up of only straight lines, there are a few easy ways to create guides that you can snap to.

The first is to duplicate the object and use 'Object → Objects to Guides'. Now you can switch to node-editing mode, double-click the segment you want to add a node to and use snapping to snap to the guide intersection.

[image: Snapping a new node to the intersection of guides created with 'Object to Guides']

By the way, if you want to use 'Objects to Guides' without having to duplicate the object, then you can enable the 'Keep objects after conversion to guides' setting in the preferences under 'Tools' (click on 'Tools' directly, not expanding the category).

Alternatively, you can enable snapping for guides, paths and 'Tangential lines', then drag a new guide from the rulers onto any point on the segment, to create a new tangential guide that extends that line.

[image: Snapping popup with the 'Tangential lines' setting highlighted]

[image: Snapping a new tangential guide onto the path segment]

Lastly, you can snap the guide origin to one node, then shift-drag it onto the opposite one to manually rotate it into place.

[image: Manually rotate guide with snapping]

Comment: Dude, thank you. You've given me what seems like the missing piece to the puzzle of SVGs. To anyone that's still a beginner like me, the way I removed the guides (since tons of them are made) is by going to `Extensions` -> `Render` -> `Guides creator` check `Delete existing guides` -> `Apply`